# How can I restore a backup without overwriting ALL of the tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, restore

I have a SQL Server database with 3 tables.  I need to restore a backup that contains *4* tables, while still keeping the old data in the original 3 tables.  Is this possible?

Comment: One way to do it is offered by kevinsky. The short answer is "no". There's no such thing as a partial restore in SQL Server. If you utilized 3:rd party backup sw, then such might have that option. But not with the built-in support. All or nothing.

Answer (score 8):

Restore the backup to a database with a new name.  You get to keep the old and new and can move tables between them with a little work